# Expected a ';' error when creating a variable of struct type

Tags: c++

Code is given below :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

struct vertex {
    bool visited;
    int value;
    int distance;
};

int main() {

    int key_value;
    std::cin >> key_value;

    int num_vertices;
    std::cin >> num_vertices;

    int** matrix;
    matrix = new int*[num_vertices];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[num_vertices];
    }

    vertex* vertices;
    vertices = new vertex[num_vertices];

    std::deque<vertex> queue;

    int vertex, value;
    while(std::cin >> vertex >> value) {
        vertices[vertex].value = value;
        int num_edges;
        std::cin >> num_edges;
        for(int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++) {
            int edge_to;
            std::cin >> edge_to;
            matrix[vertex][edge_to] = 1;
        }
    }

    //BFS

    vertices[0].visited = true;
    vertices[0].distance = 0;
    queue.push_back(vertices[0]);

    while(!queue.empty()) {
        vertex cur_v;
        cur_v = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();
        for(int i = 1; i < num_vertices; i++) {
            if(matrix[cur_v, i]) {
                if(!vertices[i].visited) {
                    vertices[i].visited = true;
                    queue.push_back(vertices[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return(0);
}
```

I am getting the following errors,

> search_gilene_matt.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
>   search_gilene_matt.cc:42: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘cur_v’
>   search_gilene_matt.cc:43: error: ‘cur_v’ was not declared in this scope

Can someone shed some light on what would be causing this?

I have looked for a missing semicolon but I don't have any idea of where it would be.

Comment: Are you using cur_v outside the loop?

Comment: Does the code compile and run correctly? IntelliSense errors may be a bug in the IDE, they are different to program errors

Comment: no cur_v is only used inside the loop, also not just an intellisense error, doesn't compile as well

Comment: And when you get compiler errors, what are those? When having compiler errors, always please include them, complete and unedited, in the question. Also mark out on which line in the shown code the errors are.

Comment: @MattGilene You need to post more code then, to the point where we can reproduce it.  What you have here compiles.

Comment: How about providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) instead of a bunch of dots?

Comment: You cannot have dynamic sized arrays!
And `queue` cannot be used as a variable name!

Comment: `cur_v, i` shouldn't use the comma operator... you want `][`. Separately, compilers tend to do something really helpful - *tell you the line number the error's on*. How about putting a big `// ERROR HERE!` in your code listing...?

Comment: `int vertex, value;` shadows the type `vertex`

Comment: Idk if @Tony is on to something, but I've never seen a comma used in a square bracket. Hard to say without line numbers.

Comment: @GargAnkit: obviously Matt's using a compiler that supports dynamic array sizes - who cares? That's his portability decision. And `queue` can be a variable name... it's not a reserved word, just a very poor choice.

Comment: Ahh, that fixed it, did realized i created a variable with the same name as my type. And yeah the comma in square bracket thing, totally missed that, not sure how it even compiled. Don't know what I was thinking when I typed it in. Also thanks for all the criticism on my post, first time actually posting my own question. Will keep in mind for next time

Comment: Nitpick: `return` is not a function - you don't need to put `()` around the value, and indeed `main` returns 0 implicitly by default....

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you declared `int vertex` which is hiding your `struct vertex`.  Rename the int and you're good.

Answer (score 3):

When you write:

```
int vertex, value;
```

then `vertex` becomes the name of a variable so long as that variable is in scope.

Later you write:

```
vertex cur_v;
```

which fails because `vertex` is the name of a variable.

To fix this, either name your variable something different, or use `struct vertex` to refer to the type.

Comment: This answer is clear, explains the problem and the solution well.